# Como buscar uma letra em uma string com Golang?

Tags: golang

Eu preciso pegar uma string do usuário e verificar se 
1) A primeira letra começa com i ou I 
2) A última letra termina com n ou N 
3) Se a string tema letra a ou A pelo meio.

Eu comecei a escrever algo desse tipo, e usei a string package mas o programa continua dando erro

```
func main() {
    var s string
    fmt.Println("Type a word")
    fmt.Scan(&s)
    //procurar na string
    verificaA := strings.Contains(s, "A")
    verificaa := strings.Contains(s, "a")
    num := len(s)

    if s[0] == 'i' || s[0] == 'I' {
        if s[num-1] == 'n' || s[num-1] == 'N' {
            if verificaA == true || verificaa == true {
                fmt.Println("Found!")
            }
        }
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Not Found!")
    }
}
go
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não sei onde você pretende usar esse código, mas uma solução alternativa seria o uso de expressões regulares.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    s := "IiiiIiII    a   A    NnNnN"
    matched, err := regexp.MatchString(`^(?i)i.*a.*n$`, s)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Printf("found: %v\n", matched)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/da2Og7NIwz8

PS: Se você for usar esse código em um "tight loop", é melhor você compilar a expressão regular com `regexp.MustCompile` para obter mais desempenho.